# Can i pass Entire Cart in Kentico CMS to paypal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, kentico

I'm using Kentico CMS to make something like shopping cart website

I Know there is Shopping cart web Part i can Use it in Kentico and configure it but 
this is not what i'm looking for

so, can i pass entire Cart (categories) to the Paypal or what exactly the mechanism of passing 
more than one category on shopping cart web site at Once(as total shopping cart) to payment gateway like Paypal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default functionality when the payment type is set to paypal (version 7).

See CMSDesk->Ecommerce->Configuration->Payment Types
and Site Manager -> Settings -> E-commerce -> Payment Gateways -> PayPal

See the demo ecommerce site, which implements PayPal gateway.

and http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/ecommerceguide/index.html?paypal.htm for more detail setting it up.

You can also set up sandbox buyers and sellers with PayPal to test with; with a developer PayPal account.